# ImageReader method of reportlab library does not work

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reportlab

reportlab ImageReader('url') of PIL library does not work.
my env: Python 3.7.6, Pillow 7.0.0, reportlab 3.5.32 (i tried also different version of PIL and reportlab... same error)

```
img = ImageReader('https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
```

my error

```
Cannot open resource "https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
fileName='https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x119474090 filename='https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved...Solution using urls images inside tables on reportlab:

```
from PIL import Image as pillowImage
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.platypus import Image

cloud_image = default_storage.open('url') # using s3Storage 
img = pillowImage.open(cloud_image)
img_byte_arr = BytesIO()
img.save(img_byte_arr, format=img.format)
result = Image(img_byte_arr, w * cm, h * cm)

....
data1 = [[result]]

t1 = Table(data1, colWidths=(9 * cm))
t1.setStyle(TableStyle([('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),]))
t1.hAlign = 'LEFT'

story.append(t1)
...
```